# EntityManager results in nullPointerException. Using Seam and JBOSS

Tags: drop-down-menu, jboss, nullpointerexception, seam, converters

I am making a web-based application using SEAM and JBOSS. I am trying to make a converter for a drop-down box, but whenever I use entityManager within the converter class I get a NullPointerException. I have spent a couple days trying to figure this help and any help would be appreciated

Here is some of my code. If anymore is needed, just let me know:

Converter Class:

```
package edu.uwrf.iss.flowershop.entity;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.ConverterException;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import org.jboss.seam.annotations.In;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.Scope;

public class EmpConverter implements Converter {

@In
private EntityManager entityManager;

public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, String arg2) {
    int num = Integer.parseInt(arg2);
    entityManager.refresh(getClass());
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT e FROM FlowerStoreDelivery WHERE e.deliveryId LIKE :num")
                    .setParameter("num", num);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, query.getResultList());
    FlowerStoreEmployee emp = entityManager.find(FlowerStoreEmployee.class, arg2);
    return emp;
}

public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object arg2) throws ConverterException {

return Integer.toString(((FlowerStoreEmployee)arg2).getEmployeeId());
}
}
```

And this is where the converter is used:

```
    <my:dropdown label="Employee ID" id="emp" value="#{deliveryPort.emp}"required="false">
                    <f:converter converterId="EmpConverter" />
                    <s:selectItems value="#{deliveryPort.empList}" var="emp" label="#{emp.employeeId} #{ emp.nameFirst}"/> 
                </my:dropdown>
```

Comment: what is the point of the entityManager.refresh() call?

Comment: It was just to test what part of the code was erroring out

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have figured the problem out. There was a missing line of code in my components.xml file. Thank you all for your responses.

Comment: Good job!  Why don't you provide the details of the missing line of code for future readers with this problem?  After you're done, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted'.  Cheers~

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the @In on none-Seam components.

What you can do is

```
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, String arg2) {
 EntityManager entityManager = (EntityManager) Component.getInstance("entityManager");
  ...
  ...
}
```